# Which embedded Database for client base application is best for following needs?

Tags: database, visual-studio, encryption, cross-platform, embedded-database

1. In-build Encryption support
2. Full Text Search
3. Boolean Search
4. C/C++, VB availability
5. Cross Platform (Linux & Mac & Windows)

The other features which may be available are:

1. Compression of Database
2. UDF's
3. Replication and database synchronization

First five are must and other are the additional features

Answer (score 1):

**Firebird Embedded**.

You can get it from [Firebird](https://www.firebirdsql.org)
and its [UDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20231130110334/https://www.ibphoenix.com/download/tools/udf)